# Django: how to get the related set of a related set of an object

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say I have the following three interconnected models setup:

```
class Organisation():
    ....

class Job():
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('Organisation', null=True, blank=True, related_name="jobs", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Candidate():
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', related_name='candidates', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

That is, each `Organisation` has many `jobs`, and in turn each `Job` has many `candidates`.

From this, I know how to get all ofthe `jobs` (the "job set") related to an `organisation` with `organisation.jobs.all()`.

Q. ***So putting all of this together - how could I get all of the `candidates` related to an `Organisation`?***

My mind is just drawing a blank...and I can't seem to find any use cases online ... would anyone know the ORM shorthand for such a chained relationship?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new FK field to the Candidate model

```
class Candidate():
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', related_name='candidates', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('Organisation', null=True, blank=True, 
    related_name="<any_name>", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With organisation.jobs.all() you will get a query of all jobs, and later you can loop through them and pull all candidates for each Job.

The shortest way is to add a method inside Organisation model:

```
def get_candidates(self):
        return [job.candidates.all() for job in self.jobs.all() if job.candidates.all().exists()]

def prefetch_candidates(self): 
    queryset = self.jobs.all().prefetch_related('candidates') 
    return [q.candidates.all() for q in queryset]
```

It will returl a list of candidates for each job if there is any candidate to avoid empty queryset for non-candidate jobs.

Test with number of queries using prefetch[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I am comfortable with looping in this fashion ... performance?

Comment: Well, this is the fastest way I can think right now:
def prefetch_candidates(self):
        queryset = self.jobs.all().prefetch_related('candidates')
        return [q.candidates.all() for q in queryset]

And here are results of some test I made:
56 Organisations, 2389 Candidates

https://imgur.com/a/2cCmKLo

First method I wrote - 14 queries, with prefetch - only 2

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a QuerySet of `Candidate` instances the most logical conclusion is to filter on `Candidate`. One can use `__` to span relationships in lookups:

```py
result = Candidate.objects.filter(job__organisation=some_organisation_instance)
```

Reference [Lookups that span relationships [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)